# using sqlite with fltk to print output

Tags: fltk

Please guys I have no idea on how to print output from sqlite database to fltk multiline output. Help to just point me in the right direction. Thanks. I'm making a management app as my final project and my defense is near already

Comment: 1) Can you get the result of the query from sqlite to the console?  2) Can you get from the contents of an array to an fltk multiline output?

Comment: Your question is too vague, please provide a SSCCE. You might take a look at a project of mine: github.com/andreldm/kissplayer. It makes use of FLTK and SQLite, HTH.

Comment: Yes I can print to the console